# Java DOM XML PARSER, how to get text values from document with that structure?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

How to use JAVA DOM XML PARSER with an XML structure like this, can anybody give me an example, I have to do it in 3 hours.
the document looks sth like this:

```
<mainNode>
 <header>
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
 </header>
 <part1>
    <inside>
     <1>text1</1>
     <2>text2</2>
    </inside>
 </part1>
 <part2>
    <inside>
     <1>text1</1>
     <2>tex2</2>
    </inside>
 </part2>
</mainNode>
```

I need to get the 1 and two text values from a big file.

Comment: This is not [valid XML](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp) and as such no XML parser will help you. An XML element name **cannot** start with a number.

Comment: that's not the point, I've just given an example of the structure. The document is much bigger and it has correct names.

Comment: That _is_ the point. Not only does this question show no effort your example XML is entirely useless. Voting to close.

Comment: I'm reading the doc for the DOM parser, and my "no effort" as you said may be explained by the fact that i have  no like 2 h 10 min to do that.

Comment: Regardless of your deadlines this isn't a code writing service. This forum is designed to be a place where questions as asked about concrete issues encountered.